# pasar un arreglo a una funcion en c

Tags: c, codeblocks

si realizo todo en la main me lo toma, pero el ejercicio exige realizarlo en una funcion, a lo que lo traslado pero no recorre todo el arreglo

```
void leerfactura (int a[], int sizeA,int fft){
  
for (int i=0;i<sizeA;i++){
       if (a[i]>fft){

        printf( "la factura %d es superior al promedio de montos\n",i+1);

       }
       else printf("la factura %d es inferior al promedio de montos\n",i+1);
    return 0;
   }

 }
```

esa es la funcion y este el codigo principal

```
int main()
{
    int sizeA,i;
    float fi,ft,fft;
    fi=0;
    ft=0;
    printf("ingrese la cantidad de facturas que quiere registrar: ");
    scanf("%d",&sizeA);
    int a[sizeA];

    for (i=0;i<sizeA;i++){
    printf("ingresé el monto de la factura %d:",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    ft=ft+a[i];
    fi=fi+1;

    }
    fft=ft/fi;
    //for (int i=0;i<sizeA;i++){
    //     if (a[i]>fft){
      //   printf ("la factura %d es superior al promedio de montos\n",i+1);
       // }

    //}

    printf("el promedio es: %.2f\n",fft);
    leerfactura(a,sizeA,fft);

    return 0;
}
```

Estuve revisando tutoriales y no consigo ver el error, ya que realizo los pasos tal cual los veo e interpreto

Comment: Ese `return 0;` que tienes después del `else` en la función `leerffactura()` se va a ejecutar siempre, sin importar el resultado del `if` previo; por lo mismo, el `for` sólo ciclará una sola vez sin importar el valor de `sizeA`

Comment: muchisimas gracias!, ahi lo solucione! mil gracias!